# Why my program is consuming a bunch of memory?

Tags: c++, image, opengl, memory

I'm doing a game based in layers(to make a parallax effect) and I need to crop a image from each layer to compose a scene. But something is acumulating in memory and I don't know what is. I filled my code with `delete[]` as a desperate measure to fix.

**ImageClass.h**

```
#include <math.h>

class Image {
public: 
    Image(int w, int h){
     width = w; height = h;
     pixels = new int[w*h*3];
  }

    Image(){}

  void setPixel(int a, int r, int g, int b, int x, int y){
      pixels[x + y * width] = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
  }

  int getPixel(int x, int y){
     return pixels[x+y*width];
  }
  int getWidth(){ return width; }

  int getHeight(){ return height; }

  int* getPixels() {
      return pixels;
  }

  void composition(int xi, int yi, int *foreground, int fw, int fh) {
      for (int i = yi; (i < fh) && (i < height); i++) {
          for (int j = xi; (j < fw) && (j < width); j++) {
              int aF = (foreground[j + i * fw] >> 24) & 0xff;
              int rF = (foreground[j + i * fw] >> 16) & 0xff;
              int gF = (foreground[j + i * fw] >> 8) & 0xff;
              int bF = (foreground[j + i * fw]) & 0xff;

              int rI = (pixels[j + i * width] >> 16) & 0xff;
              int gI = (pixels[j + i * width] >> 8) & 0xff;
              int bI = (pixels[j + i * width]) & 0xff;

              float am = aF / (float)255;

              int c1 = (rF * am) + rI * (1 - am);
              int c2 = (gF * am) + gI * (1 - am);
              int c3 = (bF * am) + bI * (1 - am);

              pixels[j + i * width] = (aF << 24) | (c1 << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3;
          }
      }
      delete[] foreground;
  }

private:
    int *pixels;
        int width, height;
};
```

---

**Layer.h**

```
#include <fstream>
#include "ImageClass.h"

using namespace std;

class Layer {
    private:
        Image *img;
        float scrollY;
        float scrollX;
        float ypos;
        float xpos;

    public:
        Layer(){
            img = NULL;
            scrollX = 0;
            scrollY = 0;
            ypos = 0;
            xpos = 0;
        }

        Layer(Image *pImg, float sy, float sx, float yp, float xp) {
            img = pImg;
            scrollX = sx;
            scrollY = sy;
            ypos = yp;
            xpos = xp;
        }

        Layer(char* path, float sy, float sx, float yp, float xp) {
            ifstream arg(path);
            if (!arg.is_open()) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            char word[10];

            //Reading type
            arg >> word;

            //Reading width
            int argWidth;
            arg >> word;
            argWidth = atoi(word);

            //Reading height
            int argHeight;
            arg >> word;
            argHeight = atoi(word);

            //Reading max
            arg >> word;

            //Creating an image with arg size
            img = new Image(argWidth, argHeight);

            int a, r, g, b;
            for (int i = 0; i < argHeight; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < argWidth; j++) {
                    arg >> word;
                    a = atoi(word);
                    arg >> word;
                    r = atoi(word);
                    arg >> word;
                    g = atoi(word);
                    arg >> word;
                    b = atoi(word);
                    img->setPixel(a, r, g, b, j, i);
                }
            }

            arg.close();
            //End of reading

            scrollX = sx;
            scrollY = sy;
            ypos = yp;
            xpos = xp;
        }

        int* subImage(int wp, int hp) {
            int* subPixels = new int[wp * hp];
            for (int i = 0; (i < hp) && (i < img->getHeight()); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; (j < wp) && (j < img->getWidth()); j++) {
                    subPixels[j + i * wp] = img->getPixel(j + xpos, i + ypos);
                 }
            }
            return subPixels;
            delete[] subPixels;
        }

        void horizontalScrolling(bool direction){
            //if direction equals true, it goes to the right. Else, left
            if (direction) {
                xpos += scrollX;
            } else {
                xpos -= scrollX;
            }
        }

        void verticalScrolling(bool direction){
            //if direction equals true, it goes up. Else, down
            if (direction) {
                ypos -= scrollY;
            } else {
                ypos += scrollY;
            }
        }

        float getScrollX() {
            return scrollX;
        }

        float getScrollY() {
            return scrollY;
        }

        float getPosX() {
            return xpos;
        }

        float getPosY() {
            return ypos;
        }

        void setPosX(float xp){
            xpos = xp;
        }

        void setPosY(float yp){
            ypos = yp;
        }

        Image* getImage() {
            return img;
        }

};
```

---

```
#include "Layer.h"
#include <math.h>

class Scene {
    private:
        int width;
        int height;
        Layer *layers[10];
        Image *finalScene;

    public:
        Scene(int w, int h) {
            width = w;
            height = h;
            finalScene = new Image(w, h);
            loadLayers();
        }

        void loadLayers() {
            //loading layer 0
            layers[0] = new Layer("Background", 1, 1.5, 0, 0);
            layers[1] = new Layer("Island", 5, 5, 0, 0);
        }

        void mountScene() {
            delete[] finalScene;
            finalScene = new Image(width, height);
            finalScene->composition(0, 0, layers[0]->subImage(width, height), width, height);
            finalScene->composition(0, 0, layers[1]->subImage(width, height), width, height);
        }

        void sceneHScrolling(bool direction) {
            int cont = 0;
            int layersCreated = 2;
            while (cont < layersCreated) {
                int delta = layers[cont]->getImage()->getWidth() - width;
                int posX = layers[cont]->getPosX();
                if (direction) {
                    if (posX < (delta)) {
                        layers[cont]->horizontalScrolling(direction);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (posX
 > 0) {
                        layers[cont]->horizontalScrolling(direction);
                    }
                }
                cont++;
            }
        }

        void sceneVScrolling(bool direction) {
            int cont = 0;
            int layersCreated = 2;
            while (cont < layersCreated) {
                int delta = layers[cont]->getImage()->getHeight() - height;
                int posY = layers[cont]->getPosY();
                if (direction) {
                    if (posY > 0) {
                        layers[cont]->verticalScrolling(direction);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (posY < delta) {
                        layers[cont]->verticalScrolling(direction);
                    }
                }
                cont++;
            }
        }

        int* getScene() {
            return finalScene->getPixels();
        }

        Layer* getLayer(int i){
            return layers[i];
        }
};
```

Comment: TL;DR.... but in general you might want to try memory debugging tools. A starting point is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Just two hints: a) Use valgrind. b) For the future: delete is not only nice to have, but absolutely nessecary. Missing = bug. Adding as desperate measure will probably fail because your missing some places where it should be.

Comment: .... or adding it on places where it shouldn't be :D

Comment: To start: Where do you delete Image.pixels (the first variable i´ve seen...)? (and, your second Image constructor looks bad. Uninit. pointer etc.without any checks later...)

Comment: You need to design some approach to memory management. Classes that own allocated memory must destroy it, usually in a destructor (is funny you don't have a destructor in any of the classes).

Comment: Try to reduce the code in your question to the lines that are actually relevant for it (in this case, lines that handle memory)

Answer (score 3):

> I filled my code with delete[] as a desperate measure to fix.

You need to be a bit more disciplined than that. **Every** `new[]` needs to be balanced with a `delete[]` and every `new` with a `delete`. So adding `delete` calls is much more than just a desperate measure: it's essential.

Otherwise you'll leak memory, which is what's happening here.

Alternatively, why not use `std::vector<int>` *etc.* instead? That way, all the memory is managed for you.

Comment: Yes but OP littered the code with `deletes` at places where they don't belong.